# Issues with assigning licenses using MS Graph powershell module

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to assign licenses for new users based on the job title entered. When created it should query that job title and find the first user alphabetically with the same job title and grab their licensing information. Then assign those licenses to the new user, but it is assigning no license.

I have tried changing the code multiple times and finally got to a point where the script doesn't error out, but its still not assigning the licenses.

```
$GraphUser = New-MgUser @GraphUserParams
$NewGraphUser = $GraphUser.UserPrincipalName
$NewGraphUser = $NewGraphUser.ToString()

$ReferenceUser = Get-MgUser -Filter ("jobTitle eq '$userJobTitle'") | Sort-Object DisplayName
$ReferenceUser = $ReferenceUser | Where-Object {$_.UserPrincipalName -ne $NewGraphUser}

if ($ReferenceUser.Count -gt 0) {
  $firstUser = $ReferenceUser[0]
  $firstUPN = $firstUser.UserPrincipalName
                
  $mgUser  = Get-MgUser -UserId "$firstUPN"
  $ReferenceLicense = Get-MgUserLicenseDetail -UserId "$firstUPN"

  foreach ($license in $ReferenceLicense.licenses) {
         Set-MgUserLicense -UserPrincipalName $NewGraphUser -LicenseId $ReferenceLicense.SkuId
                }
```

Comment: What type of authentication is being used.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts.  Most systems are migrating to OAUTH2 which works on Windows, MAC, and Linux.  It is a two step authentication process where step one is to get a token and step two is to perform a query with the token. New-MgUser has a authentication parameter that may not be set : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/new-mguser?view=graph-powershell-1.0